# Confused by this function

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a needleman-wunsh algorithm for pairwise alignment. I've been able to create a score_matrix and a traceback_matrix, but I am having trouble understanding this traceback function which traverses the traceback matrix. My main problem is that I do not understand why I am getting this error though it seems simple:

```
--------------------------------------
IndexErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-378-758f4e7985a2> in <module>()
     68 
     69 
---> 70 traceback(traceback_matrix, score_matrix, seq1, seq2)

<ipython-input-378-758f4e7985a2> in traceback(traceback_matrix, score_matrix, seq1, seq2, start_row, start_col)
     30             for aligned_seq, input_seq in zip(aligned_seqs1, seq1):
     31                 print("aligned_seq:", aligned_seq, "input_seq:", input_seq)
---> 32                 aligned_seq.append(str(input_seq[current_col-1]))
     33                 print("aligned_seq_new:", aligned_seq)
     34             for aligned_seq, input_seq in zip(aligned_seqs2, seq2):

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Here is the function:

```
def traceback(traceback_matrix, score_matrix, seq1, seq2, start_row=start_row, start_col=start_col):
    """Traverse traceback_matrix to get optimal alignments
    """
    _traceback_encoding = {'match': 1, 'vertical-gap': 2, 'horizontal-gap': 3,
                       'uninitialized': -1, 'alignment-end': 0}

    aend = _traceback_encoding['alignment-end']
    match = _traceback_encoding['match']
    vgap = _traceback_encoding['vertical-gap']
    hgap = _traceback_encoding['horizontal-gap']
    uninitialized = _traceback_encoding['uninitialized']
    gap_character = '-'

    aligned_seqs1 = [[] for e in range(len(seq1))]
    aligned_seqs2 = [[] for e in range(len(seq2))]

    current_row = start_row
    #print("current_row:", current_row)
    current_col = start_col

    best_score = score_matrix[current_row, current_col]
    print("best_score:", best_score)
    current_value = None

    while current_value != aend:
        current_value = traceback_matrix[current_row, current_col]
        print("current_value:", current_value, "current_row:", current_row, "current_col:", current_col)

        if current_value == match:
            for aligned_seq, input_seq in zip(aligned_seqs1, seq1):
                print("aligned_seq:", aligned_seq, "input_seq:", input_seq)
                aligned_seq.append(str(input_seq[current_col-1]))
                print("aligned_seq_new:", aligned_seq)
            for aligned_seq, input_seq in zip(aligned_seqs2, seq2):
                #print("aligned_seq2:", aligned_seq, "input_seq2:", input_seq)
                aligned_seq.append(str(input_seq[current_row-1]))
            current_row -= 1
            current_col -= 1
        elif current_value == vgap:
            for aligned_seq in aligned_seqs1:
                aligned_seq.append(gap_character)
            for aligned_seq, input_seq in zip(aligned_seqs2, seq2):
                aligned_seq.append(str(input_seq[current_row-1]))
            current_row -= 1
        elif current_value == hgap:
            for aligned_seq, input_seq in zip(aligned_seqs1, seq1):
                aligned_seq.append(str(input_seq[current_col-1]))
            for aligned_seq in aligned_seqs2:
                aligned_seq.append(gap_character)
            current_col -= 1
        elif current_value == aend:
            continue
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                "Invalid value in traceback matrix: %s" % current_value)

    for i in range(len(seq1)):
        aligned_seq = ''.join(aligned_seqs1[i][::-1])
        constructor = str
        aligned_seqs1[i] = constructor(aligned_seq)

    for i in range(len(seq2)):
        aligned_seq = ''.join(aligned_seqs2[i][::-1])
        constructor = str
        aligned_seqs2[i] = constructor(aligned_seq)

    return aligned_seqs1, aligned_seqs2, best_score, current_col, current_row
```

**Input:** a score matrix, traceback matrix, sequence1, sequence2, start_row, start_column

score_matrix:

```
(array([[  0.,  -2.,  -4.,  -6.,  -8., -10., -12., -14., -16., -18., -20.],
        [ -2.,  -2.,  -3.,  -5.,  -7.,  -9., -11., -13., -15., -17., -19.],
        [ -4.,  -4.,  -3.,   1.,  -1.,  -3.,  -5.,  -7.,  -9., -11., -13.],
        [ -6.,  -6.,  -5.,  -1.,  -1.,  -3.,   8.,   6.,   4.,   2.,   0.],
        [ -8.,   2.,   0.,  -2.,  -3.,  -3.,   6.,   6.,  14.,  12.,  10.],
        [-10.,   0.,   7.,   5.,   3.,   1.,   4.,   4.,  12.,  19.,  17.],
        [-12.,  -2.,   5.,  11.,   9.,   7.,   5.,   4.,  10.,  17.,  18.],
        [-14.,  -4.,   3.,   9.,   9.,   8.,   6.,   4.,   8.,  15.,  22.]])
```

traceback_matrix:

```
array([[0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3],
        [2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3],
        [2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1],
        [2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1]]))
```

seq1 and seq2:

```
seq1 = "HEAGAWGHEE"
seq2 = "PAWHEAE"
```

start_row and start_col:

```
start_row = score_matrix.shape[0]-1
start_col = score_matrix.shape[1]-1
```

The output should be the following aligned sequences and their score:

```
HEAGAWGHE-E
-PA--W-HEAE
1.0
```

Ideally where the error occurs, we would want to place input_seq into the current_col-1 position of aligned_seqs1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the provided code, you can see this one line in the output:

```
aligned_seq: [] input_seq: H
```

This is produced by the `print` right above the line that throws an exception.

Let's take a closer look:

```
for aligned_seq, input_seq in zip(aligned_seqs1, seq1):
print("aligned_seq:", aligned_seq, "input_seq:", input_seq) 
aligned_seq.append(str(input_seq[current_col-1]))   # <--- Error
```

I can only guess, that your assumption was that `zip` would concatenate every element from `aligned_seqs1` with `seq1`, but what it actually does, it breaks `seq1` into the single characters, so your `input_seq` is always one character long. That's why referring to anything further than first character will throw an error.

If you just comment the line that throws an error, you will see the full output, and you would see that `input_seq` holds every character from initial `seq1` one by one.

I hope this helps you with your further progress. Let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: Thanks for helping! So i'm now aware that input_seq is always one character long, but I still can't find an effective way of inserting input_seq into the appropriate position in aligned_seqs1.

Ideally what is for that first line to create a new aligned_seqs1 that is [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], ['H']]. Or is there an easier way to achieve what you correctly guessed was what I originally wanted to do?